# automatic change spaces and period to underscore

Tags: php, mysql, string, format

I would like to know if there is a way not automatically format my data from ".data" to "_data" or "data name" to "data_name" ?

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $app_id=>$val) {
        if ($app_id != "submit") {
            $prof_rate = $_POST[$app_id];
            $tokens = explode("-", $app_id);
            $label = $tokens[0]; 
            $applicationId  = $tokens[1];
            // insert query technology_results
            echo $label.":".$prof_rate."<br/>";
        }
    }
} else {
    $app_val_err = "Error Message!";
}
```

Comment: Which values are you trying to format?

Comment: this one $label = $tokens[0];

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `preg_replace` to replace all spaces and dots with underscores:

```
$input = "some.name here";
$output = preg_replace("/[ .]/", "_", $input);
```

Comment: thank you but it returns only the first letter of the string can suggest other way?